# javascript call inside a bookmark

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, bookmarks

wondering if it is possible to have a javascript call inside a html bookmark like:

```
<a href="bookmark">Go down</a>
.
.
.
<a name="down" href="javascript:alert('movedhere')">
```

so when visitor clicks on "Go down" the alert message appears **but also** when `url="/#bookmark"` then again the function is called.

Comment: Please clarify. Do you just want to assign the same behavior when 2 different elements are clicked?

Comment: I have a link to a location in the same page and i want a javascript call in the bookmark. So if visitor either clicks on the link or visits http://example.com/#bookmark then the javascript function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **neither scalable nor elegant** but it *would work* if you checked the [`fragment`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) of the current page when the page loads:

```
<script>
function myCallback()
{
    alert('movedhere');
}
</script>

<a href="#down" onclick="myCallback()">Go down</a>
.
.
.
<a name="down">

<script>
var frag = window.location.hash;
if (frag === '#down')
{
    myCallback();
}
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that exactly, but you can add the script to the actual link instead.

```
<a href="#down" onclick="alert('movedhere')">Go down</a>
.
.
.
<a name="down">
```

Comment: thank you, but i actually want the function to be called even when visitor visits  example.com/#bookmark